# compare two arrays and remove partial match in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const arr1=['hello from the other side', 'very nice boy,john']
const arr2=['nice', 'work']

output = ['work']
```

I am stuck on this problem idk the right code for it in nodejs. when I do string to word it works and when I do word to string it doesn't work.
how can I filter the word array by matching the sentence array?

```js
var cleanArray = c.filter(element => c.every(item => !element.includes(item)));
```

This is my current code and it works only from sentence to word and not word to sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
> passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true
> if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function
> returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array. - MDN

```js
const arr1 = ["hello from the other side", "very nice boy,john"];
const arr2 = ["nice", "work"];

const result = arr2.filter((s) => !arr1.some((str) => str.includes(s)));
console.log(result);
```